# 12.04 -desktop-i386 *new to linux*

Tags: 12.04, usb

Today I got a .iso file of ubuntu named : "ubuntu 12.04 -desktop-i386.iso". So have few queries about it as I am new to all this:

Question: Will I be able to dual boot it with windows 7 home premium ?
Question: i will make a bootable pen drive for this, so using a 1 GB pen drive(completely formatted) will be enough ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will be able to dual boot it with windows 7, while installation select install besides windows, and using the 1 GB pen drive will be enough for making a installation bootable media, I recommend using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). The [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) is also an option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How much HDD should i allocate to this version of ubuntu?

Comment: You need at least 5GB to install ubuntu, but i would recommend at least 15 GB if you have the space,I can help you if you can tell me how much HDD space do you have also do you know what a swap partition is ?

Comment: How much do you have? I would say that the absolute bare minimum for comfortable use with Ubuntu is 40 GB. If you can spare more, that's awesome. Usually, assigning half the disk to Ubuntu and half the disk to Windows works, too.

Comment: I have 65 GB of storage empty in the drive where windows is installed. And I don't really know about swap partition :(

Comment: Hmm, to be exact now you have 65 GB of empty space in your drive that is unpartitioned, or you have 65 GB free in the partition where windows is installed ?

Comment: I think i have 65 GB free in the partition where windows is installed. To be precise i have two drives: C (total- 97GB out of which 65 GB is free) and D (total 51 GB out off which 12 GB is free) and Windows is installed in C drive.

Comment: And if it is needed i can empty 10-15 GB from C drive and will transfer it to a external 1 TB HDD.

Comment: What do you have on the other drive ? If possible i would recommend moving the data from that drive to the windows drive and installing ubuntu on the second drive, if you don't want that option however, we have to get a little complicated, first off you can use simple method : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer , or you can shrink your windows partition a bit so you can fit ubuntu in but that is far more complicated, try the wubi installer ( in the link ) and tell me how does the situation look like

Comment: What is the problem in installing in Drive C where windows is already installed? Out of total 65 GB i will allocate 15 GB to ubuntu. Won't it work in that case?

Comment: OK we will install it on C download the installer i wrote about above and follow the instruction

Comment: Can't do it using bootable pendrive ? I have already make it using that 1 GB pendrive. And what was the concern due to which you were recommending to install on the other drive?

Comment: I would not recommend using Unetbootin. Maintenance on the project is iffy and it has failed me and others multiple times. Easy USB Creator is fantastic and has a much higher success rate: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: I am concerned you might accidentally delete your windows partition my friend, look let me explain it to you, if you want to install linux to your drive and dual boot it with windows you need to partition your disk, and partitions are like "disks within the disk", but you only have one partition within the disk, you need to shrink that partition for 20 GB and then make a new partition on witch you are going to install ubuntu, you getting me ? I know this sounds complicated

Comment: Why not simply leave the decision making up to the installer? During setup, it asks whether you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. It is perfectly safe to just select that option and move on.

Comment: I got it, watch this video and tell me if it helped : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4

Comment: Have successfully installed it yesterday yesterday itself just forgot to mention here. Thanks.
Now just have one problem: i accidentally allocated Ubuntu 50 GB and leftover to windows. Any chance i can allocate more to windows and less to ubuntu without installing either of them again.

Comment: Yes you can use any partition editor for that matter i recomend doing it with gparted you should be aible to find a good turtorial online google how to shrink or extend a partition in gparted :)